# FFMPEG- Audio Channel Issue

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

We have source file IMX 50 mxf which has 8 interleave audio channel and 7,8 audio is left and right stereo. we need to replace 1,2 audio channel in source with 7,8 stereo channel. we are using below ffmpeg command.

```
C:\Users\Iplay>"D:\Test\FFAStrans0.9.2 (1)\Processors\ffmpeg\x64\ffmpeg.exe" -i D:\YAHAN_MAIN_GHAR_GHAR_KHELI_EP583_CREATIVE_MASTER.mxf -ss 5  -c:v copy -acodec pcm_s24le -ac 2 -map 0:0 -map 0:1.7.8  -gop_timecode 00:00:00:00 -timecode 00:00:00:00 -f mxf_d10 -timecode 00:00:00:00 D:\Test\test212.mxf
```

we didn't getting stereo output. please find attached mediainfo of source. for output i need 7,8 audio channel.[Source mediainfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUshs.png)

Comment: Your source has 8 channels. Do you want to output only 2 (7+8)?

Comment: Yes.. 7,8 stereo

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mxf -ss 5 -map 0:0 -c:v copy
       -map 0:1 -af "pan=stereo|c0=c6|c1=c7" -acodec pcm_s24le
       -timecode 00:00:00:00 -f mxf_d10 out.mxf
```

`gop_timecode` is only put in effect when transcoding to MPEG-2.